# Find $E[X^2]$ given the probability mass function

Tags: probability

We are given that the pmf is $h(z) = \displaystyle\frac{z^2+2}{22}$ for $z\in \{0,1,2,3\}$.

When finding $E[X^2]$ would it be:

$$(1^2)\cdot \displaystyle\frac{(1^2)^2+2}{22}+(2^2)\cdot\displaystyle\frac{(2^2)^2+2}{22}+...+(4^2)\cdot \displaystyle\frac{(4^2)^2+2}{22}$$?

or:

$$(1^2)\cdot \displaystyle\frac{(1)^2+2}{22}+(2^2)\cdot\displaystyle\frac{(2)^2+2}{22}+...+(4^2)\cdot \displaystyle\frac{(4)^2+2}{22}$$

(b) What is the moment-generating function of $Z$?

**My attempt:**

$h(1)=\displaystyle\frac{1^2+2}{22}=\frac{3}{22}$

$h(2)=\displaystyle\frac{2^2+2}{22}=\frac{6}{22}$

$h(3)=\displaystyle\frac{3^2+2}{22}=\frac{11}{22}$

$h(0)=\displaystyle\frac{0^2+2}{22}=\frac{2}{22}$

So the $mgf$ is:

$M(t)=\displaystyle\frac{3}{22} e^t +\frac{6}{22} e^{2t} + \frac{11}{22} e^{3t}+\frac{2}{22}$

Can someone check?

Comment: @Hugo i typed my domain wrong..it is not $\{1,2,3,4\}$ it is $\{0,1,2,3\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E[X^2]  = \sum_{x=0}^{\color{red}3} x^2h(x)$$

The second one is correct if the index starts from $0$ and ends with $3$.

Edit:

For the mgf, note that $\exp(0) = 1$.

Comment: i also added a second part to this problem..if you wouldn't mind taking a look at it

Comment: You missed out a term.

Comment: $h(0)=\frac{0^2+2}{22}=\frac{2}{22}$

Comment: yup, you have to add that to the mgf.